# Rmarkdown TOC links (internal to document) don't work

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, r-markdown, tableofcontents

When I create an html Rmarkdown that includes a TOC, the links only work as long as the html file is on my drive. As soon as I publish or share it, the links break because they are hardcoded to the document on my drive. Is there a way around this? e.g., having a link with a relative path.

Example:

```
---
title: "TOC test"
author: "Me"
date: "January 18, 2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
---

###Header1 {#Header1}  
some text here

###Header2 {#Header2}  
some more text here

####Header2b {#Header2b}
and more text here
```

My link addresses look like this:

```
file:///C:/Data/PROJECTS/Testing/TOCtest.html#header1
```

UPDATE:including the Rmd

````
---
title: "###**Weekly Update**"
author: "#####Author"
date: "#####Report Date: `r Sys.Date()`  "
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
---

#### **MY FIRST HEADER**  

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

##### **MY FIRST SUB-HEADER**  

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

#### **MY SECOND HEADER**  

You can also embed plots, for example:


##### **MY SECOND SUB-HEADER**  

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

UPDATE: including the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0088)file:///C:/Data/PROJECTS/TestLinks.html -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="generator" content="pandoc">
<title></title>

<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,LyohIGpRdWVyeSB2MS4xMS4zIHwgKGMpIDIwMDUsIDIwMTUgalF1ZXJ5IEZvdW5kYXRpb24sIEluYy4gfCB
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8,html%7Bfont%2Dfamily%3Asans%2Dserif%3B%2Dwebkit%2Dtext%2Dsize%2Dadjust%3A100%25%3B%2Dms%2Dtex
<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,LyohCiAqIEJvb3RzdHJhcCB2My4zLjUgKGh0dHA6Ly9nZXRib290c3RyYXAuY29tKQogKiBDb3B5cmlnaHQ
<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,LyoqCiogQHByZXNlcnZlIEhUTUw1IFNoaXYgMy43LjIgfCBAYWZhcmthcyBAamRhbHRvbiBAam9uX25lYWw
<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,LyohIFJlc3BvbmQuanMgdjEuNC4yOiBtaW4vbWF4LXdpZHRoIG1lZGlhIHF1ZXJ5IHBvbHlmaWxsICogQ29
<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,CgovKioKICogalF1ZXJ5IFBsdWdpbjogU3RpY2t5IFRhYnMKICoKICogQGF1dGhvciBBaWRhbiBMaXN0ZXI
<link href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8,%2Ehljs%2Dliteral%20%7B%0Acolor%3A%20%23990073%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ehljs%2Dnumber%20%7B%0Acolor%3A%2
<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,LyohIGhpZ2hsaWdodC5qcyB2OS4xMi4wIHwgQlNEMyBMaWNlbnNlIHwgZ2l0LmlvL2hsanNsaWNlbnNlICo

<style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
<style type="text/css">
  pre:not([class]) {
    background-color: white;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.hljs) {
  hljs.configure({languages: []});
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
  if (document.readyState && document.readyState === "complete") {
    window.setTimeout(function() { hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); }, 0);
  }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
  font-size: 34px;
}
h1.title {
  font-size: 38px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.table th:not([align]) {
  text-align: left;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="./TestLinks_files/MathJax.js.download"></script><style type="text/css">.MathJax_Hover_Frame {bord
.MathJax_Menu_Button .MathJax_Hover_Arrow {position: absolute; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border: 2px solid #AAA; border
.MathJax_Menu_Button .MathJax_Hover_Arrow span {display: block; background-color: #AAA; border: 1px solid; border-radius: 3px; line-h
.MathJax_Hover_Arrow:hover {color: white!important; border: 2px solid #CCC!important}
.MathJax_Hover_Arrow:hover span {background-color: #CCC!important}
</style><style type="text/css">#MathJax_About {position: fixed; left: 50%; width: auto; text-align: center; border: 3px outset; paddi
#MathJax_About.MathJax_MousePost {outline: none}
.MathJax_Menu {position: absolute; background-color: white; color: black; width: auto; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; margi
.MathJax_MenuItem {padding: 2px 2em; background: transparent}
.MathJax_MenuArrow {position: absolute; right: .5em; padding-top: .25em; color: #666666; font-size: .75em}
.MathJax_MenuActive .MathJax_MenuArrow {color: white}
.MathJax_MenuArrow.RTL {left: .5em; right: auto}
.MathJax_MenuCheck {position: absolute; left: .7em}
.MathJax_MenuCheck.RTL {right: .7em; left: auto}
.MathJax_MenuRadioCheck {position: absolute; left: 1em}
.MathJax_MenuRadioCheck.RTL {right: 1em; left: auto}
.MathJax_MenuLabel {padding: 2px 2em 4px 1.33em; font-style: italic}
.MathJax_MenuRule {border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC; margin: 4px 1px 0px}
.MathJax_MenuDisabled {color: GrayText}
.MathJax_MenuActive {background-color: Highlight; color: HighlightText}
.MathJax_MenuDisabled:focus, .MathJax_MenuLabel:focus {background-color: #E8E8E8}
.MathJax_ContextMenu:focus {outline: none}
.MathJax_ContextMenu .MathJax_MenuItem:focus {outline: none}
#MathJax_AboutClose {top: .2em; right: .2em}
.MathJax_Menu .MathJax_MenuClose {top: -10px; left: -10px}
.MathJax_MenuClose {position: absolute; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border: 2px solid #AAA; border-radius: 18px; -webkit-
.MathJax_MenuClose span {display: block; background-color: #AAA; border: 1.5px solid; border-radius: 18px; -webkit-border-radius: 18p
.MathJax_MenuClose:hover {color: white!important; border: 2px solid #CCC!important}
.MathJax_MenuClose:hover span {background-color: #CCC!important}
.MathJax_MenuClose:hover:focus {outline: none}
</style><style type="text/css">.MathJax_Preview .MJXf-math {color: inherit!important}
</style><style type="text/css">.MJX_Assistive_MathML {position: absolute!important; top: 0; left: 0; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); 
.MJX_Assistive_MathML.MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block {width: 100%!important}
</style><style type="text/css">#MathJax_Zoom {position: absolute; background-color: #F0F0F0; overflow: auto; display: block; z-index:
#MathJax_ZoomOverlay {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 300; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;
#MathJax_ZoomFrame {position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 0; width: 0}
#MathJax_ZoomEventTrap {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 302; display: inline-block; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; b
</style><style type="text/css">.MathJax_Preview {color: #888}
#MathJax_Message {position: fixed; left: 1em; bottom: 1.5em; background-color: #E6E6E6; border: 1px solid #959595; margin: 0px; paddi
#MathJax_MSIE_Frame {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0px; z-index: 101; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px}
.MathJax_Error {color: #CC0000; font-style: italic}
</style><style type="text/css">.MJXp-script {font-size: .8em}
.MJXp-right {-webkit-transform-origin: right; -moz-transform-origin: right; -ms-transform-origin: right; -o-transform-origin: right; 
.MJXp-bold {font-weight: bold}
.MJXp-italic {font-style: italic}
.MJXp-scr {font-family: MathJax_Script,'Times New Roman',Times,STIXGeneral,serif}
.MJXp-frak {font-family: MathJax_Fraktur,'Times New Roman',Times,STIXGeneral,serif}
.MJXp-sf {font-family: MathJax_SansSerif,'Times New Roman',Times,STIXGeneral,serif}
.MJXp-cal {font-family: MathJax_Caligraphic,'Times New Roman',Times,STIXGeneral,serif}
.MJXp-mono {font-family: MathJax_Typewriter,'Times New Roman',Times,STIXGeneral,serif}
.MJXp-largeop {font-size: 150%}
.MJXp-largeop.MJXp-int {vertical-align: -.2em}
.MJXp-math {display: inline-block; line-height: 1.2; text-indent: 0; font-family: 'Times New Roman',Times,STIXGeneral,serif; white-sp
.MJXp-display {display: block; text-align: center; margin: 1em 0}
.MJXp-math span {display: inline-block}
.MJXp-box {display: block!important; text-align: center}
.MJXp-box:after {content: " "}
.MJXp-rule {display: block!important; margin-top: .1em}
.MJXp-char {display: block!important}
.MJXp-mo {margin: 0 .15em}
.MJXp-mfrac {margin: 0 .125em; vertical-align: .25em}
.MJXp-denom {display: inline-table!important; width: 100%}
.MJXp-denom > * {display: table-row!important}
.MJXp-surd {vertical-align: top}
.MJXp-surd > * {display: block!important}
.MJXp-script-box > *  {display: table!important; height: 50%}
.MJXp-script-box > * > * {display: table-cell!important; vertical-align: top}
.MJXp-script-box > *:last-child > * {vertical-align: bottom}
.MJXp-script-box > * > * > * {display: block!important}
.MJXp-mphantom {visibility: hidden}
.MJXp-munderover {display: inline-table!important}
.MJXp-over {display: inline-block!important; text-align: center}
.MJXp-over > * {display: block!important}
.MJXp-munderover > * {display: table-row!important}
.MJXp-mtable {vertical-align: .25em; margin: 0 .125em}
.MJXp-mtable > * {display: inline-table!important; vertical-align: middle}
.MJXp-mtr {display: table-row!important}
.MJXp-mtd {display: table-cell!important; text-align: center; padding: .5em 0 0 .5em}
.MJXp-mtr > .MJXp-mtd:first-child {padding-left: 0}
.MJXp-mtr:first-child > .MJXp-mtd {padding-top: 0}
.MJXp-mlabeledtr {display: table-row!important}
.MJXp-mlabeledtr > .MJXp-mtd:first-child {padding-left: 0}
.MJXp-mlabeledtr:first-child > .MJXp-mtd {padding-top: 0}
.MJXp-merror {background-color: #FFFF88; color: #CC0000; border: 1px solid #CC0000; padding: 1px 3px; font-style: normal; font-size: 
.MJXp-scale0 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.0); -moz-transform: scaleX(.0); -ms-transform: scaleX(.0); -o-transform: scaleX(.0); transfo
.MJXp-scale1 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.1); -moz-transform: scaleX(.1); -ms-transform: scaleX(.1); -o-transform: scaleX(.1); transfo
.MJXp-scale2 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.2); -moz-transform: scaleX(.2); -ms-transform: scaleX(.2); -o-transform: scaleX(.2); transfo
.MJXp-scale3 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.3); -moz-transform: scaleX(.3); -ms-transform: scaleX(.3); -o-transform: scaleX(.3); transfo
.MJXp-scale4 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.4); -moz-transform: scaleX(.4); -ms-transform: scaleX(.4); -o-transform: scaleX(.4); transfo
.MJXp-scale5 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.5); -moz-transform: scaleX(.5); -ms-transform: scaleX(.5); -o-transform: scaleX(.5); transfo
.MJXp-scale6 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.6); -moz-transform: scaleX(.6); -ms-transform: scaleX(.6); -o-transform: scaleX(.6); transfo
.MJXp-scale7 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.7); -moz-transform: scaleX(.7); -ms-transform: scaleX(.7); -o-transform: scaleX(.7); transfo
.MJXp-scale8 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.8); -moz-transform: scaleX(.8); -ms-transform: scaleX(.8); -o-transform: scaleX(.8); transfo
.MJXp-scale9 {-webkit-transform: scaleX(.9); -moz-transform: scaleX(.9); -ms-transform: scaleX(.9); -o-transform: scaleX(.9); transfo
.MathJax_PHTML .noError {vertical-align: ; font-size: 90%; text-align: left; color: black; padding: 1px 3px; border: 1px solid}
</style></head>

<body><div id="MathJax_Message" style="display: none;"></div>

<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
code {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
.tabbed-pane {
  padding-top: 12px;
}
button.code-folding-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
</style>



<div class="container-fluid main-container">

<!-- tabsets -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.buildTabsets("TOC");
});
</script>

<!-- code folding -->
<div class="fluid-row" id="header">
<h1 class="title toc-ignore"></h1><h3 id="weekly-update"><strong>Weekly Update</strong></h3>
<h4 class="author"><em><h5 id="author">Author</h5></em></h4>
<h4 class="date"><em><h5 id="report-date-2018-02-02">Report Date: 2018-02-02</h5></em></h4>

</div>

<div id="TOC">
<ul>
<li><a href="file:///C:/Data/PROJECTS/TestLinks.html#my-first-header"><strong>MY FIR
<li><a href="file:///C:/Data/PROJECTS/TestLinks.html#my-first-sub-header"><strong>MY
</ul></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:/Data/PROJECTS/TestLinks.html#my-second-header"><strong>MY SE
<li><a href="file:///C:/Data/PROJECTS/TestLinks.html#my-second-sub-header"><strong>M
</ul></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="my-first-header" class="section level4">
<h4><strong>MY FIRST HEADER</strong></h4>
<p>This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more de
<div id="my-first-sub-header" class="section level5">
<h5><strong>MY FIRST SUB-HEADER</strong></h5>
<p>When you click the <strong>Knit</strong> button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of a
<pre class="r"><code class="hljs">summary(cars)</code></pre>
<pre><code class="hljs">##      speed           dist       
##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
##  Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00</code></pre>
</div>
</div>
<div id="my-second-header" class="section level4">
<h4><strong>MY SECOND HEADER</strong></h4>
<p>You can also embed plots, for example:</p>
<div id="my-second-sub-header" class="section level5">
<h5><strong>MY SECOND SUB-HEADER</strong></h5>
<p>Note that the <code>echo = FALSE</code> parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the
</div>
</div>

</div>

<script>

// add bootstrap table styles to pandoc tables
function bootstrapStylePandocTables() {
  $('tr.header').parent('thead').parent('table').addClass('table table-condensed');
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  bootstrapStylePandocTables();
});


</script>

<!-- dynamically load mathjax for compatibility with self-contained -->
<script>
  (function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src  = "https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  })();
</script>



</body></html>
```

UPDATE: sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ggrepel_0.6.5    Rcpp_0.12.14     rprojroot_1.2    digest_0.6.12    grid_3.4.0       plyr_1.8.4       backports_1.1.1 
 [8] gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     evaluate_0.10.1  scales_0.5.0     ggplot2_2.2.1    stringi_1.1.6    rlang_0.1.4     
[15] lazyeval_0.2.1   rmarkdown_1.7    tools_3.4.0      stringr_1.2.0    munsell_0.4.3    rsconnect_0.8.5  yaml_2.1.14     
[22] compiler_3.4.0   colorspace_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6  knitr_1.17       tibble_1.3.4
```

Comment: Your `sessionInfo()` results show that you are using an older version of R and some key packages, such as `rmarkdown` and `knitr`. Can you please try rendering your `.Rmd` in a clean and updated environment? I believe your problem is something local.

Comment: @KevinArseneau: yes, smg local just not sure what. started everything in new project with updated R, knitr and rmarkdown, but same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write this as a comment initially but then decided to answer because of length and that this understanding of HTML output from R markdown could be helpful for other users.

Firstly, the TOC links are already relative and not *hardcoded* as you say. If you look at the source of your output document after `rmarkdown::render("example.Rmd")`, you will see...

#### example.Rmd

````
---
title: "###**Weekly Update**"
author: "#####Author"
date: "#####Report Date: `r Sys.Date()`  "
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
---

#### **MY FIRST HEADER**  

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

##### **MY FIRST SUB-HEADER**  

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

#### **MY SECOND HEADER**  

You can also embed plots, for example:


##### **MY SECOND SUB-HEADER**  

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

#### example.html

```
<div class="fluid-row" id="header">

<h1 class="title toc-ignore"><h3 id="weekly-update"><strong>Weekly Update</strong></h3></h1>
<h4 class="author"><em><h5 id="author">Author</h5></em></h4>
<h4 class="date"><em><h5 id="report-date-2018-02-03">Report Date: 2018-02-03</h5></em></h4>

</div>

<div id="TOC">
<ul>
<li><a href="#my-first-header"><strong>MY FIRST HEADER</strong></a><ul>
<li><a href="#my-first-sub-header"><strong>MY FIRST SUB-HEADER</strong></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#my-second-header"><strong>MY SECOND HEADER</strong></a><ul>
<li><a href="#my-second-sub-header"><strong>MY SECOND SUB-HEADER</strong></a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="my-first-header" class="section level4">
<h4><strong>MY FIRST HEADER</strong></h4>
<p>This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <a href="http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com" class="uri">http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com</a>.</p>
<div id="my-first-sub-header" class="section level5">
<h5><strong>MY FIRST SUB-HEADER</strong></h5>
<p>When you click the <strong>Knit</strong> button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:</p>
<pre class="r"><code>summary(cars)</code></pre>
<pre><code>##      speed           dist       
##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
##  Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00</code></pre>
</div>
</div>
<div id="my-second-header" class="section level4">
<h4><strong>MY SECOND HEADER</strong></h4>
<p>You can also embed plots, for example:</p>
<div id="my-second-sub-header" class="section level5">
<h5><strong>MY SECOND SUB-HEADER</strong></h5>
<p>Note that the <code>echo = FALSE</code> parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.</p>
</div>
</div>




</div>
```

In your links, the *href* values are pointing to the section id. From your browser, the path will be the location to the file with the section as a suffix.

> *i.e.* `protocol://path/to/file/example.html#section`

I cannot reproduce what you are generating, please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question and lets have a look.

Comment: @KevinArsenau: I did as you suggested using rmarkdown::render("my file.Rmd"). It generates and html but the TOC links are still "hardcoded" to my local drive. They look like this: file:///C:/Data/PROJECTS/myfile.html#intro so I'm confused. When I share this file the links don't work.

Comment: @val, did you examine the html file? Post the contents of the output as I did in my answer

Comment: @KevinArsenau: I have included the html. you'll note that my hrefs are still hardcoded to my drive: href="file:///C:/Data/PROJECTS/TestLinks.html#my-first-header"> I don't understand why.

Comment: @val, thank you, could you please edit your rmarkdown to include a space between your section headers, like this `### Header 1 {#header 1}`?

Comment: @KevinArsenau: OK, i did that but i get the same issue. I've included the Rmd in the question this time.

Comment: @val, I can't replicate your problem, I'll edit my solution with your new information. Could you please post your `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @KevinArsenau: Thank you for persisting. session info added to bottom of question.